# texture(...) function always returns 0

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3

I have been trying to get shadow mapping to work for quite some time now and I am still no closer than I was a month ago. I am beginning to think it may be an issue with my GL drivers because I haven't been able to see any side effects such as "light acne."

I was told to start using a `sampler2DShadow` instead of a `sampler2D` and this is what I did. However, whenever I sample the map using `texture(...)` the result is always 0. Why would this be happening?

I have tried entering manual depthCoord values and I still get 0. Could this be a result of the shadowMap itself (i.e the way it has been setup?) or is it a driver issue?

**Framebuffer Setup**

```
FramebufferName = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 512, 512, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depthTexture, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap;
in vec4 depthCoord;
void main(){
    //The final color after lighting is stored as 'FinalColor'
    float visibility = 1.0;
    if (texture(shadowMap, depthCoord.xyz) == 0.0){
        visibility = 0.1;
    }
    color = vec4(finalColor.rgb * visibility, 1.0);
}
```

**Rendering Code**

```
    glm::vec3 lightInvDir = glm::vec3(0,-10,-10);
    glm::mat4 depthProjectionMatrix = glm::ortho<float>(-10,10,-10,10,-10,20);
    glm::mat4 depthViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(lightInvDir, glm::vec3(0,0,0), glm::vec3(0,1,0));
    glm::mat4 depthModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    glm::mat4 depthMVP = depthProjectionMatrix * depthViewMatrix * depthModelMatrix;
    glm::mat4 biasMatrix(
                0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0
    );
    glm::mat4 depthBiasMVP = biasMatrix*depthMVP;

    /*  Shadow */
    subShader->useShader();
    glViewport(0,0,512,512);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(subShader->getShader(),"depthMVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, &depthMVP[0][0]);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Shadows::framebuffer());
    renderBuffer(objBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    /* Clear */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Shader */
    objShader->useShader();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Shadows::shadowmap());
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(objShader->getShader(),"shadowMap"),0);

    /* Render Scene */
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(objShader->getShader(),"depthBiasMVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, &depthBiasMVP[0][0]);
    glViewport(0,0,640,480);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(objShader->getShader(),"renderingPass"),1.0);
    renderBuffer(objBuffer);
```

The majority of this code has been learned from sites such as (http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/) with modifications based on (http://www.fabiensanglard.net/shadowmapping/index.php) and the red book.

Comment: do you have an intel, amd, or NVidia GPU?

Comment: I see you're binding the framebuffer texture to read from it, but are you unbinding it afterwards? If a texture is bound to a framebuffer, you cannot render to it, nor even clear it, while that texture is also bound to a texture unit.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Did you solve it?